# как быстро узнать какой тип заменяет auto?

Tags: c++

как быстро узнать какой тип заменяет auto в коде?
может есть какая-то функция специальная по типу typeid, но которая там всякие *, & и тд не отбрасывает?

Comment: Укажите, какую IDE или что еще вы используете.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void PrintType()
{
    std::cout << 
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    __FUNCSIG__
    #else
    __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
    #endif
    << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    auto x = 42;
    PrintType<decltype(x)>(); // void PrintType() [T = int]
}
```

Но вообще, современные IDE должны уметь сами говорить тип. Все, что на основе Clangd, точно умеет (например VSCode с плагином Clangd вместо стандартного C++-плагина).